# Where would I receive http request in AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Am beginner to Amazon web services. 
I have a below lambda python function

```
import sys
import logging
import pymysql
import json
rds_host=".amazonaws.com"
name="name"
password="123"
db_name="db"
port = 3306
def save_events(event): 
result = []
conn = pymysql.connect(rds_host, user=name, passwd=password, db=db_name, 
connect_timeout=30)
with conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor) as cur:
cur.execute("select * from bodyPart")
result = cur.fetchall()
cur.close()
print ("Data from RDS...")
print (result)
cur.close()
bodyparts = json.dumps(result)
bodyParts=(bodyparts.replace("\"", "'"))

def lambda_handler(event, context):
 save_events(event)
 return bodyParts
```

using an above function am sending json to the client using API gateway, now suppose user selects an item from the list and send it back, in form of json where will i get http request and how should i process that request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made an additional information for @Harsh Manvar.

The easiest way I think is you can use 
[api-gateway-proxy-integration-lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html#api-gateway-proxy-integration-lambda-function-python)

Currently API Gateway support AWS lambda very good, you can pass request body (json) by using *event.body* to your lambda function.

I used it everyday in my hobby project (a Slack command bot, it is harder because you need to map from *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* to *json* through mapping template)

And for you I think it is simple because you using only *json* as request and *response*. The key is you should to select *Integratiton type* to *Lambda function*
[image]

You can take some quick tutorials in Medium.com for more detail, I only link the docs from Amazon.

@mohith: Hi man, I just made a simple approach for you, you can see it here.

The first you need to create an API (see the docs above) then link it to your Lambda function, because you only use **json**, so you need to check the named **Use Lambda Proxy integration** like this:
[image]
Then you need to deploy it!

Then in your function, you can handle your code, in my case, I return all the event that is passed to my function like this:

[image]

Finally you can post to your endpoint, I used postman in my case:
[image]

I hope you get my idea, when you successfully deployed your API then you can do anything with it in your front end.

I suggest you research more about CloudWatch, when you work with API Gateway, Lambda, ... it is Swiss army knife, you can not live without it, it is very easy for tracing and debug your code.

Please do not hesitate to ask me anything.

Answer (score 1):

you can use aws service called API-gateway it will give you endpoint for http api requests.

this api gateway make connection with your lambda and you can pass http request to lambda.

here sharing info about creating rest api on lambda you can check it out : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-create-api.html

aws also provide example for lambda GET, POST lambda example.you just have to edit code it will automatically make api-gateway.as reference you can check it.

From Lambda Console > create function > choose AWS serverless repository > in search bar type "get" and search > api-lambda-dynamodb > it will take value from user and process in lambda.

here sharing link you can direct check examples : https://console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/home?region=us-east-1#/create?tab=serverlessApps